# Blender texture paint

Tags: texture-painting

[image]I would like to ask if anyone knows a solution for my problem.

After I paint my texture in blender (it looks ok in blender) and export it, in other software like Unity, 3dsMax or sketchup the texture is very blurry... I even tried to make a 8K texture... but every soft other then blender looses the quality. How can I export the object to keep the texture fine?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is difficult without examples, please update your question. Make sure you are using a lossless format like .png

Comment: I updated the post with the image and I was using .PNG

Comment: what if you manually import the texture file directly onto a new object in Unity, 3D max, sketchup. There is no reason that you should lose resolution. How are you getting the Blender data into these apps? I know unity supports .blend directly via drag and drop. are you exporting and if so is a separate .PNG file being created? and does that look ok in an image editor like GIMP?